# In socket programming how to make a server listen for limited no of clients?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I am working on socket programming using c language and linux platform and my requirement is to make a server listen only for two or three clients. How is it possible ?

Comment: From here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html: `int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);. The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the queue of pending connections for sockfd may grow.` Is `backlog` what your are looking for?

Comment: You are aware, that even if the server listens to "*only 2 or 3 clients*" it can successivly connect to an unlimited (limited only by system resources) number of clients in parallel. You might want to provide more specify requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you make that by specifying second argument on listen() call.
i assume that you are using TCP protocol.
from man pages:

```
int listen(int sockfd, int backlog);
```

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the  queue 
>   of  pending
>          connections for sockfd may grow.  If a connection request arrives when the queue
>          is full, the client may receive an error with an indication of ECONNREFUSED  or,
>          if  the  underlying protocol supports retransmission, the request may be ignored
>          so that a later reattempt at connection succeeds.

so for two clients - you call listen like: `listen(fd, 2);`

suggested reading: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html#listen

Comment: No. The backlog argument only controls how many connections can exist before they are accepted, and the platform can vary the actual number up or down, undetectably.

Answer (score 0):

Close the listening socket when you reach the limit, and open it again when one of the clients disconnects.

*Or*

Leave it open but stop accepting connections while you're at the limit.

The backlog parameter to `listen()` has nothing to do with any of this, contrary to other answers and comments here.